# Paypal in Itunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, paypal, app-store-connect, banking

Not programming related, but it is related to the submission of apps to apple so I will post this question here:

I have searched the net for a while, and I have found no discussions about this; will apple deposit money into a Paypal account? Eg. If I add a paypal account into Itunes connect, will apple consider this to be a valid bank account and deposit all earnings as though it was a normal bank account?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible to use Paypal to receive payments from Apple.

See [iTunes Connect FAQ](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/2.0.0.9.1.9.1.1.8.1)

> **How are payments made?**
>   All payments are made by Electronic Funds Transfer. When available, payments are sent by low value ACH, as
>   opposed to high value wire transfer. Apple's bank will consolidate
>   payments for different financial reports when possible, generally
>   resulting in a single payment for all earnings each month the
>   requirements for being paid have been met.
>
> The payment method used (Wire/ACH) is displayed at the bottom of the
>   presentation of payments on the Payments page.